# How to access "start" path?

Tags: php

I was searching for answer but didn't find any.

My question is, how can I access "start" path of my website?

I have file right here:

```
www.website.com/app/logout.php
```

and this file is part of header. Header is included to every file with

```
include ("header.php");
```

and I can determine here how far away root is, and can make it like:

```
include ("../header.php");
```

Now I have a lot of other files in my website which are here:

```
www.website.com/app/file2.php
www.website.com/app/path/file3.php
www.website.com/app/path/path2/file4.php
www.website.com/app/path/path2/path3/file5.php
```

How can I access from all above files to logout.php?

"app" folder can be changed to any other name, so it can be:

```
www.website.com/new_app/
```

And I want to make this work from everywhere in the website, and even if app folder name would be changed.

Also the link to the website can be changed to second one:

```
www.website2.com
```

Is there any universal solution?

==== UPDATED ====

I have two files:

```
app/header.php
app/logout.php
```

The `logout.php` is a part of `header.php`

Now, if I include my file to for ex `/app/path/path2/file.php`:

`include ("../../header.php");`

how can I redirect to `logout.php` in my `file.php` with `a href="whathere?/logout.php"` in `header.php`?

PS. I can't determine it myself, because `header.php` is one file for every other file (good solution for updates, one file instead of tons with same content in every subfolder)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want to access the second level from anywhere in your php file? Why do you want to access logout.php from each file? What do you mean access from each file? Link to? Import from?

Comment: simply relatively: `../logout.php` or `../../logout.php`. You could determine in each file how far from root you are to know how many levels you need to go up.

Comment: `logout.php` is a part of header in my website and can be accessible everywhere. I can't determine how many levels I am far from root, cuz how? - header is included with php to every file.

Comment: _"how many levels I am far from root, cuz how?"_ you have `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to tell you that (an explode on '/' should give you the direction).

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found possible solution:

Just create `defines.php` and add code:

```
<?php
   define ("app_dir", "/app");
?>
```

And include it in `header.php`:

```
include ("defines.php");
```

Now I can use it everywhere and access my `logout.php` with:

```
<a href="<?php echo app_dir; ?>/logout.php">
```

If my dir name will change I just can change and update `defines.php`

PS. Above solution works only for `a href` not for `include`, `require_once`, `include_once` etc.